# How do I apply a color gradient to a stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, stroke, creative-cloud

I can see the color gradient when my mouse is over the stroke but once I move my mouse away, the gradient goes away with it. How do I apply the gradient, I have been at this for 3 hours?! I am using Illustrator CC.

My specific problem is that I cannot apply a color gradient to a stroke. It is a straight vertical line I am using as a time line.

This far, I have edited the colors I want the gradient to be and along the stroke line I can see the colored gradient I made, it has arrows along it for me to edit the colors further if I prefer and that's where I am stuck. I do not need to edit the colors and more, they are what I like them to be.

Now I am trying to move on to the next step but I do not know how to make the colored gradient stay after I am done editing it.

Comment: Maybe it's taking you so long because you don't have any software :) You need to at least post what application you are using.

Comment: What's the Stroke Panel look like? What's the Appearance Panel look like? Have you *actually* applied the gradient to the stroke?

Comment: It sounds like you made the gradient but are just not applying the gradient to the stroke.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure at what point you are unable to apply the gradient. Here is a very short tutorial on how to apply a gradient to a stroke.

First create the gradient in the gradient panel

[image: gradient panel]

Once you're done picking the swatch colors you will want to save the gradient as a swatch.

Click on the "new swatch" button next to the trash icon and save that gradient as a swatch and name it whatever fits.

[image: save swatch]

Select your line and pick the stroke swatch pallet and select your new gradient swatch.

[image: stroke]

End result

[image]