# Illustrator: applying gradient to multiple objects not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I created a logo by converting my text to outlines. Grouped them together using the pathfinder - unite feature.  I'd like to apply a single gradient to the group, but for some reason I can't. Nothing happens when I drag over the gradient tool over the group. What could be the problem?

Comment: Not sure, but does [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76114/52050) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select your group of objects (presumably the converted text)
- With this selected, click on the gradient swatch you need from the `Swatches` palette. This will apply the gradient to each letter individually. Make sure you apply this for the `Fill` and not the `Stroke`
- Press `G` then drag your mouse from one side to another of the group and play with this until you get what you need. Holding down `Shift` while you drag will keep the gradient horizontal or vertical

Comment: Great. If you dont mind try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above, to the left of the bullets. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you combined the text using the Pathfinder tool it is still not a compound path. You can complete this by navigating to ***Object > Compound Path***, or by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.